# IPA becoming unobtainium, can I use denatured alcohol to clean vintage computers?

Tags: vintage, cleaning

Due to COVID-19 and peoples' practice of hoarding, IPA is becoming incredibly difficult to find where I live (and online).  Since we are all home so much these days, I like spending *some* of that time restoring vintage computers.  My normal routine is to clean the PCB's with 99.9% IPA and use denatured alcohol for cleaning stubborn pen marks, etc. on the case.  I often use glass cleaner for the plastic cases too.

I have a bit of denatured alcohol which doesn't seem to be hard to get.  So my question is, will I damage my electronics by using denatured alcohol (pictured below) to clean the boards?

**EDIT**

From what I understand, denatured alcohol is an umbrella term for the fact of adding a denaturing ingredient to alcohol.  This could be lots of stuff like kerosene.  One reason is to prevent people from drinking it.  Also, IPA is denatured as well (again, from my understanding).  But if it helps any, this is typically what I use:

[image: Denatured Alcohol]

Comment: This may be a good question to ask over on [Retrocomputing.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also, *where* do you live? For example, in German, the chemical is usually called 2-Propanol.

Comment: Ethanol is the primary ingredient in my PCB flux cleaner. So if something is in denatured alcohol to damage your boards, it is not the ethanol.

Comment: don't know, doesn't seem to be unobtainable to me, if you're willing to pay lab prices http://h832884620k371.catalogus.de/832884620/371/AD368/ODM4NjcxNA==/K%C3%B6hler%20Chemie%208386714%20koehler.html

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am located in Tennessee (USA).  And I'd prefer not to pay lab prices.  :-)

Comment: I'm guessing that yes, it'll be OK.  Denatured alcohol is (usually) ethanol mixed with methanol.  It should have similar properties to IPA.  I'm not making this an answer, because -- guess.  Check the MSDS; I don't know if methanol is wors when applied to the skin than IPA, so you may want to take more care.

Comment: @TimWescott I think methanol is worse. If you drink methanol you'll die. If you drink IPA...it won't be very good for you but you won't die...at least not as quickly. At the same concentrations anyways. There's a lot more IPA in IPA than methanol in denatured alcohol I think.

Comment: Denatured alcohol usually contains a dye to make it look too bad to drink, kerosene to make you throw up if you do, and methanol to kill you if you drink enough. I'm using it instead of hand sanitiser at the moment and it seems to leave a sticky residue, which I'm not sure I'd want left on boards.

Comment: To the liqour store! Find the hardest stuff you can!

Comment: Denatured alcohol often also contains benzene and other additives. You can read them on the label typically... I would say this is not an ideal chemical to use. Some of the plastic parts on your chips could be degraded by the additives.

Comment: @Neil_UK: is the "UK" in your handle "United Kingdom"?  The denatured alcohol that I have from the hardware store here in Oregon, US of A, is just methanol and ethanol -- I guess it's one of those products where you have to say *where* it's from before folks know what's in it.

Comment: @DKNguyen: [Everclear for the win!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everclear_(alcohol))

Comment: 'IPA' (isopropyl alcohol) is *not* denatured per se, that is, it doesn't have adulterating chemicals added to it. It is inherently undrinkable (causes you to puke), but isn't especially toxic.

Comment: Even pure isopropyl can take the writing off some labels etc. I prefer hot water with a bit of detergent, and an old toothbrush to scrub stubborn areas. I clean motherboards and cases by completely submerging them in hot water. Scrub, rinse, repeat until spotlessly clean, then dry thoroughly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stuff that's sold as "denatured rubbing alcohol" here in the US is typically ethanol (90%) and methanol (10%). I would be concerned about using it to clean boards: methyl alcohol will attack some plastics.

"Denatured alcohol" like what you've shown might have other stuff in it, depending on the source. Besides methanol, this can include pyridine, benzene, acetone, MEK, isobutyl ketone, and possibly others. Again, not knowing the components on your board, these denaturants could damage it.

Here's some background on solvents from Chemtronics: https://www.chemtronics.com/Content/Images/uploaded/documents/2005V4N5HydrocarbonsvsChlorinated.pdf

You're in Tennessee, you can get 190 proof Everclear which would do the job without risking damage from methanol.

Comment: I actually already thought about Everclear (can you believe I used to sip on that in my youth?!?!?!).  One liquor store was out of Everclear.  I suppose I could hit up a few more.  :-)